# ElasticSearch Return a matched element of an array when searching

Tags: elasticsearch

I indexed documents like

```
{
  "words":[
    {
      "word":"Rakennustietosäätiö",
      "pos":[72, 3347, 97, 3642]
    },
    {
      "word":"homevauriot",
      "pos":[792, 972, 1041, 1011]
    },
    {
      "word":"mikrobivauriot",
      "pos":[1301, 972, 1572, 1005]
    },
    {
      "word":"kulkeutumisesta",
      "pos":[616, 1643, 970, 168]
    },
    {
      "word":"terveyshaitoista",
      "pos":[630, 1813, 981, 1861]
    }
  ],
  "image":"K00277_1.jpg",
  "pdf_file":"K00277.pdf",
  "page":1
}
```

Then I search by word "Rakennustietosäätiö". I would like it return the matched document but containing only the matched element. In this case, it is

```
{
  "word":"Rakennustietosäätiö",
  "pos":[72, 3347, 97, 3642]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using this structure.
To achieve this , a better approach would be [parent child](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html)

Create one parent document for each page , one child document for each word.
Now you can search word document based on condition in parent document or vice versa.
In this case item given back would be parent document or child document based on the query used.

Comment: Thanks. But with parent-child, can we have more-like-this, lets say similar parent documents based their children?

Comment: Nope , one parent for a child and any number of children for a parent. No other relations.